# Is there a full list of configuration options for .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer, ebextensions

Are you able to use this file to specify all options for an environment?
I can't find a reference online that lists all available options.
Examples of things I want to set are:

- Instance Type
- Security Groups
- Load Balancer settings (Application)

Alternatively is there a reference of all the settings that can be set in .ebextensions config files? I have found bits and pieces but can't find something that lists it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For configuration settings like instance type and security group, I would strongly recommend looking at Cloudformation; as an example of why, imagine that in the future you want (or need) to bump up your instance type. Or maybe you need to make a change to a security group that allows connections between your app and data store. Do you really want to have to *deploy application code* to do these things? Keeping infrastructure configuration in Cloudformation is in my experience a best practice.

That said, the reason you haven't been able to find a single list of settings is described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

> The option_settings section of a configuration file defines values for
>   configuration options. Configuration options let you configure your
>   Elastic Beanstalk environment, the AWS resources in it, and the
>   software that runs your application. Configuration files are only one
>   of several ways to set configuration options.
>
> The Resources section lets you further customize the resources in your
>   application's environment, and define additional AWS resources beyond
>   the functionality provided by configuration options. **You can add and
>   configure any resources supported by AWS CloudFormation, which Elastic
>   Beanstalk uses to create environments.**
>
> The other sections of a configuration file (packages, sources, files,
>   users, groups, commands, container_commands, and services) let you
>   configure the EC2 instances that are launched in your environment.
>   Whenever a server is launched in your environment, Elastic Beanstalk
>   runs the operations defined in these sections to prepare the operating
>   system and storage system for your application.

So there is not a list of all options, they are scattered about like you've found. In general though, from what I recall and this doc, there are three main pieces:

1.) option_settings (eb environment, some resource config)

2.) resources (further resource configuration)

3.) ec2-internal specific settings

I personally only use ebextensions for #3, e.g. an Apache web server config that I need to set on each ec2 instance. Resource/configuration management lives in Cloudformation.

Comment: Thanks, will look into Cloudformation more. For now I have found this page which lists a lot of the options: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html